# Phonegap 3.3/Cordova iOS Geolocation not found

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying since hours to build and run a project with always the same error:

```
2013-12-27 15:03:56.605 project[49483:70b] ERROR: Plugin 'Geolocation' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

I've tried to delete the whole platform and plugin folder and:

```
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
cordova prepare
cordova build ios
```

With several variations. The CoreLocation framework is loaded in xcode, but the Geolocation just doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the plugin wasn't added to the platform specific config.xml, so adding:

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this git URL -> https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation to add plugin into your phonegap project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to add plugin is to add their official urls like the one mentioned [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) for Geolocation